# React-Native: setState doens't update the render()

Tags: reactjs, view, react-native, refresh

Render Function:

```
render() {
return (
  <ScrollView>
    <Image style={Styles.Logo} source={require('../img/Logo.png')} />
    <List>
        {this.state.feeds.map( feedData => {
            return <ListItem
                key={feedData.id}
                title={feedData.title}
                titleStyle={Styles.Title}
                subtitle={feedData.content}
                subtitleStyle={Styles.Subtitle}
            />
        })}
    </List>
  </ScrollView>
);
}
```

AppStateChange Event:

```
_handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
    console.log("App came in the foreground.");
    this.fetchFeeds();
}
this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
}
```

FetchFeeds:

```
fetchFeeds() {
Feeds.then(res => {
  this.setState({
    feeds: res
  })
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
}
```

The "App came in the foreground" gets logged by the Console. But the view doens't update with the new information (currently a simple timestamp) altough the react documentation says that upon changing a State it will re-render. (forceUpdate() also isn't applicable here unfortunately)

Comment: have you trials to log state at `render()` calls and `componentWillUpdate()`

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console?  Declaring `fetchFeeds` in that way won't bind `this` to the component instance, so I wouldn't expect `this.setState` to work. If you do have an error, try changing it to `fetchFeeds = () => { ...`

Comment: @oklas When i go from background in foreground this is the output: `App came in the foreground.\n background\n active` in the console.

Comment: @richsilv No errors. Also debugging shows me it does work.

Comment: if you reload manually, is it rendering the new state?

Comment: @HazimAli What do you mean by reloading manually? When i restart the app it does update.

Comment: yes.. I mean restarting the app.. try to bind the fetchFeeds() inside constructor.. this.fetchFeeds() = this.fetchFeeds.bind(this) .. something like this

Comment: `this.fetchFeeds = this.fetchFeeds.bind(this)`? This is already done in the constructor.